# Download a large file from HDFS

Tags: java, file-io, hdfs

I was given DataInputStream from a HDFS client for a large file (around 2GB) and I need to store it as a file on my host.

I was thinking about using apache common IOUtils and doing something like this...

```
File temp = getTempFile(localPath);
DataInputStream dis = HDFSClient.open(filepath); // around 2GB file (zipped)
in = new BufferedInputStream(dis);
out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

I was looking for other solutions that can work better than this approach. Major concern for this is to use buffering in both input and IOUtils.copy ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For files larger than 2GB is recommended to use `IOUtils.copyLarge()` (if we are speaking about the same IOUtils: **org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils** )

The copy in IOUtils uses a default buffer size of 4Kb (although you can specify another buffer size as a parameter).

The difference between `copy()` and `copyLarge()` is the returning result.

For `copy()`, if the stream is bigger than 2GB you will succeed with the copy but the result is -1.

For `copyLarge()` the result is exactly the amount of bytes you copied.

See more in the documentation here: 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copyLarge(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)